# How to change "Show desktop" effect?

Tags: compiz, effects, show-desktop

In CCSM I set "Super+D" for showing desktop. Everything is fine but the effect. It just fade in and out. How could I change the effect for "Show Desktop"?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

In CCSM, enable Show Desktop plugin ans set it up!

Comment: I couldnt find "Show Desktop" plugin. How can I install it?

Comment: It must be in the "Desktop" section. Otherwise I suppose you're using a different version of OS/Gnome. I was supposing you were in a flaming new 12.04 ...

Comment: oops, i found it and enabled it too. But nothing changes. It still fade in/out when I press "Super+D". Am i missing something here?

Comment: It looks like the "Show Desktop" plugin is no more developed. I couldnt find any information about it in Compiz Fusion Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running 12.04, open Compiz and uncheck "Fading Windows". Wait for about a minute for all the configurations to take place and try clicking on 'Show Desktop'.

Comment: Uncheck "Fading Windows", check "Show Desktop" and set options like these: Movement direction : To corners, Windows type : type=toolbar | type=utility | type=dialog | type=normal . But the windows still fade out, except the Wine dialogs (like Photopshop Save Dialog). It's weird ...

Comment: See this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_QbxHIPi7Q&feature=youtu.be